# Uploaded mvc5 application files without publishing files in live site using code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created the MVC5 code first Website on IIS and established the site with the Application pool in Live., then I did it manually. I did not publish my application, because the IT Network team do not know the publishing process. I uploaded as it visual studio files into live, users are registering live successfully but I saw so many examples are saying to publish the site, please suggest I have to publish my application is mandatory. And If I will keep my application like now into live any issue will come in futures.

Comment: any seniors in asp.net mvc5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways supported by Visual Studio to deploy an application.  One of them is to publish it to local folder. You can publish your application to local folder, create a package and deploy it to hosting server.

Comment: created the MVC5 code first Website on IIS and established the site with the Application pool in Live is not an issue na? because my website is live now, i did not publish my applicaiotn files and directly uploaded application folders. @dj79